# Getting value of a variable from 1 method to other in java

Tags: java

One thing I awfully struggle with  in any programming language is the concept of getting a value of variable from a method to another method.  Example below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CreateGuest {

    public static String guestname(){



        Scanner userinput= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter name: ");
        String name = userinput.next();

        return name;
    }

    public void printName(){



        System.out.println("You entered " + ?? How do I get the value of name here?? );
    }

}
```

One thing I could do is have the guestname() in the printname().

```
public void printName(){



        System.out.println("You entered " + guestname() );
    }
```

If I do that then in the Main I will be getting asked for user input twice. I want to do this without deleting the 1st method.

cg.guestname();
cg.printName();

The developer in my company advised to declare name as Class variable. However isn’t that a bad practice?

Thanks

Comment: How have you learned Java? "That" never told you the basics of this language?

Comment: Keep the variable global.If the scope of the variable is local it cant be accessed from other methods or other scopes outside this local scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass it as an argument to `printName()`. E.g.,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String name = guestname();
    printName(name);
}

public static void printName(String name) {
    System.out.println("You entered " + name);
}
```

`printName()` also needs to be `static` unless you have an instance of `CreateGuest`.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use a class variable, however that's a perfectly fine thing do, as well. You can just encapsulate the field right into main:

```
public static String askUserForName() {
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter name: ");

    return userInput.next();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String guestName = askUserForName();
    System.out.println("You entered " + guestName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just keep the variable global to class scope
    import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class CreateGuest {
    private static String name="";
    public static String guestname(){



        Scanner userinput= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter name: ");
        name = userinput.next();

        return name;
    }

    public void printName(){



        System.out.println("You entered " + name );
    }

}
```